# Utilizing QtQuick Controls from PyQt5

Tags: python, pyside, pyqt5

First of all, I tried to use `QtQuick` from `PySide`. The latest PySide as of today wraps Qt 4.8, which doesn't have an actively developed desktop components. (colibri is there, but that's not for desktop, and it's buggy).

PyQt seems to win here, since the latest version (5.2.1 as of today), wraps Qt 5, which has [QtQuick](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-index.html) controls ready.

I've looked at many of the examples under `Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/examples/quick`, all of them work, but none of them use QtQuick Controls.

I am trying a very simple qml here:

```
//main.qml
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "My Application"

    Button {
        text: "Push Me"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

and a python file:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  engine = QQmlApplicationEngine("main.qml")
  engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but i'm having this error:

`.../main.qml:1 module "QtQuick.Controls" version 1.2 is not installed`

Can I use QtQuick Controls from PyQt5?. And if so, how?. I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try to use QtQuick.Controls 1.0, it works fine on my system

Comment: Yes, I tried but failed. How can I do it?. Some code please. I tried QtQuick.Controls 1.0 and the script ran but i saw nothing.

Comment: Add this one to your python code:
`code`      
win = self.engine.rootObjects()[0]
win.show()

Comment: Try adding `visible: true` to `ApplicationWindow` in your QML. Also, version 1.2 works in at least PyQt 5.3.1